# Can I pass props to <View> component in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I'm learning React, RN and confused with different types of props.

While referring to https://reactnative.dev/docs/view , here I can see list of **default** ( ?, is this correct name ) props and while learning React; I got to know that parent component passes prop to the child.

My question is can I pass **custom** ( ?, is this correct name )  to  component from parent component ?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arbitrary props to a component, but they will be ignored (unless using TypeScript, in which case you will get a compiler error). If you want to add functionality to a component, wrap it in another component and build the functionality there, parameterizing it using props if necessary

Comment: I didn't mean "arbiraty" props but one mentioned in RN documentation against component. Coming from React world, where component doesn't have its own prop, I'm confused with props passed down by parent vs component having its own props